How to Sort Rows in Excel to Match Order of a Reference Column
I'm working with a large Excel spreadsheet and need to sort rows based on the order of student IDs listed in one column, while keeping all related row data intact. The goal is to align the rows so that the student IDs in one column (F) match the order of IDs in a reference column (E). However, column F has fewer entries as some students might no longer be present. I need a way to order the existing data in F and its adjacent columns up to GI to match the order in E if it exists. If it doesnt I want to place any values that do not exist at the bottom.
Here's the current setup:
Column E (reference column): contains the desired order of all student IDs.
Column F: contains a subset of the student IDs that need to be sorted according to Column E.
Columns G to GI: contain related data that needs to move with the student IDs in Column F.
Constraints and objectives:
If a student ID from Column E is not present in Column F, that row should be moved to the bottom and both columns need to align.
The order in Column E is the authoritative list and must be preserved.
Can you suggest an approach to handle this in Excel directly, or a script in VBA? Alternatively an algorithm in C# or JS I can use to design a consol application to do this job for me.
Here is some example data.


<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Desired Order</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Our Current order</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Student Name</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Attendance %</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Grad</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">A1234</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">A1234</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Chris</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">70</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">B1234</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">C2345</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Tucker</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">75</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">C1234</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>




Have you checked out index() with match()? lots of examples of the use on here.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

You should be attempting to solve issue.  Any programming language should be able to do the work.  Choose a language and get a sort working and then if you have issues post the code and the issues.

Solar Mike beat me to it. Even when I don't need to sort my reference order, I often separate the MATCH operation into a separate column in case it's more performant to do that once per row instead of once per row per referenced column.
